# Gradle Project Always Tries to Use older version of dependency

Tags: java, gradle, migration, gradle-dependencies

I have a project structured like this:

```
-Project ROOT
 -TestProjectDir
    -gradlew
    -build.gradle
 -ServiceProjectDir
    -gradlew
    -build.gradle
```

My laptop gradle version:
7.4.2

Java version:
Java 11.0.9

My `TestProjectDir` and `ServiceProjectDir` both are using local gradle wrapper version: 7.0.2

Inside `TestProjectDir` it was using older version of dependency `org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:3.10.4`

After bumping the mockserver-netty version in `TestProjectDir` build.gradle file:

`implementation "org.mock-server:mockserver-netty:5.13.2`

I attemped to run `./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies` under `TestProjectDir` it failed and I took look at the error.

The test file which has these lines failed

```
import org.mockserver.client.server.MockServerClient;
import org.mockserver.model.Delay;
import org.mockserver.model.Header;
```

They are looking for version `3.10.4` from `.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mock-server/mockserver-netty/3.10.4` on my laptop.

I tried to delete `3.10.4` directory from the `caches` folder, now the test code cannot be compiled at all....

Looking for help desperately here !
Big Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by delete local `.gradle` folder and then reload gradle in IntelliJ